# how to import superset-ui plugins？

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, apache-superset

My superset version is v1.0.1 installed through docker-compose（just followed the instruction on official website [https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose）](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose%EF%BC%89)

Then I followed these steps to install some plugins in superset-ui repo:
https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/building-custom-viz-plugins
**but** I didn't use the `npm run dev-server` to load the plugins, because I can't get in the superset through http://localhost:9000 in this way, I don't know why, so I just followed these:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsz6W.png)

Then I run `docker-compose up`, everything looks good in outputs, but I just can't get in the superset through browser.

Should I modify the Dockerfile to run `npm link ...` ? how?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, I know, but I had the same issue and the reason was that I had not set a port. use the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8088 --name superset apache/superset
```

you can then open superset at `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give two ports to your project, one 8088 and 9000 are the first port for the back-end and the second port is for the front-end.
Then run the back-end first and finally run the front-end.
https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch

https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/building-custom-viz-plugins

Comment: Front-end:
        npm run dev-server
Back-end:
        superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger